# Why "az mysql server list" is giving me an empty array in azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am quite new to Azure, I wanted to list all the mysql servers present in my subscription but when I try running above command. It is returning an empty array even though I have got one sql server in my azure.

I tried these two commands in both azure portal CLI and local powershell and both of them are giving me an empty array.

```
az mysql server list
```

```
az mysql server list -g resourcegroupname
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You said you have sql server but you’re trying to list MySQL servers. Could that be the reason you’re getting an empty list?

Comment: Yup, I messed up with commands. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Dhanushreddy, if my post is helpful, could you pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept as an answer and close this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one [Azure SQL server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) instance in your Azure subscription and you want to list it by Azure Cli, you should use the command below:

```
az sql server list
```

Details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sql_server_list).

[Azure MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/) is another kind of SQL service.